# SQL: SELECT Statement to Return All Records, JOIN Value Is NULL, Query Returns No Records

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Statement I am executing to return data, the statement joins several other tables, so for the records returned, I can display the Name of the field, rather than the ID.

Here is part of the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetTitle,
    HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTag,
    Department.DepartmentTitle AS HardwareAssetDepartmentTitle,
    CostCentre.DepartmentTitle AS HardwareAssetCostCentreTitle,
FROM 
    HardwareAsset
INNER JOIN 
    Department Department ON (Department.DepartmentID = HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetDepartmentID)
INNER JOIN 
    Department CostCentre ON (CostCentre.DepartmentID = HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetCostCentreID)
```

My issue is that, even though the query executes successfully, because certain columns (i.e the ones mentioned above) have a value of NULL, the query seems to return no records, even though there are records within the table.

I have tried executing when records have the columns filled in and records show. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, and it should return records even when there is no match in the second table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `INNER JOIN` the join field, like `DepartmentID`, MUST have a valid record in both tables. If you want to return records from your main table regardless if they are in your join tables you have to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Cheers Guys! much appreciated, as you can probably tell, I am pretty new to SQL.